# C++ getting windows version and build as winver does?

Tags: c++, version

I'm trying to get windows version and build as winver does I can get the version and build fine but I want to also get the number that is past the build number "22631.xxxx" that one after the "." how I could do? I actually get my windows version with RtlGetVersion

```
RtlSecureZeroMemory(&os_version_info, sizeof(os_version_info));
os_version_info.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(os_version_info);
RtlGetVersion((PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOW)&os_version_info);
```

[image]